# nullable foreign key columns denormalized table vs many normalized tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

In our entitlement framework each "resource" (resource is nothing but any entity that you want to protect by assigning privileges to roles which can access or not access based on privileges) is stored in a `resource` table like below.

```
DESIGN1
RESOURCE TABLE
id  (int) | namespace (varchar) |  entity_id | black_listed (boolean)       
1         | com.mycompany.core.entity1       |24 | false
2         | com.mycompany.core.entity2       |24 | false   --note entity2
3         | com.mycompany.core.entity10      |3  | false  -- note entity10
```

each resource in the table represent different entity e.g. entity1,entity2,..,entity10. basically that's nothing but `entity1.id`, `entity2.id`, `entity3.id`, ... and so on. because `RESOURCE` table keeps resources for all kinds of entity - `entity_id` column in `RESOURCE` table can't have proper foreign key relationship constraint. we are thinking to refactor this schema such as follow

```
DESIGN 2
RESOURCE TABLE
id | description               | entity1_id | entity2_id | entity3_id | entity4_id | entity5_id | entity6_id | black_listed(boolean)
1  | com.mycompany.core.entity1|24          | null       | null       | null       |null        | null
2  | com.mycompany.core.entity2|null        | 24         | null       | null       |null        | null
```

now `entity1_id` will have a proper FK to `entity1` table , `entity2_id` will have proper FK to `entity2` and so on. downside of this approach is that this table will always have `null` values for all the columns BUT one. e.g. you can only have one `entity resource` per row. also having `null` seems to be anti pattern especially for `FK` relationship.  One other way would be normalize the schema and create a `resource` table for each `enitty` type. but that will be pretty insane to maintain and quickly become a headache. not saying it's good or bad but doesn't look like a practical design.

is there a better way to design such a table where proper FK relatinoships are also maintained? or you'll endorse Design 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one table for all entities with id (surrogate primary key) or entity_type, entity_id as unique key.

```
 id   entity_type    entity_id
 1    entity1        24
 2    entity2        24
```

Then you need to have only one column in RESOURCE referring to this table (say entities). Your RESOURCE table will look like as in the first example, but the difference is there will be only one entities table, not 10.

Comment: that's not what I am looking for. I am looking to create FK directly to each entity directly.

Comment: That need not be good design. Is there any reason why the data model is designed in that manner?

Comment: with your proposed approach - it'll require to create and maintain a "mapping" table per say and it'll be very busy table given every time ANY of the entities are inserted/deleted it'll have to updated/maintained accordingly. we are thinking having a direct FK to entity tables will leave us from that overhead and also FK will ensure deletion/insertion of items gracefully. trying to understand cons of design2 from above. why would you not recommend direct FK approach?

Comment: Not sure why there needs to be mapping table. You can create partitioned table for entities as per proposed design to keep entities segments separate.

Comment: can you elaborate with an answer? not sure I followed your last comment.

Comment: One of the reason why people go with separate tables - is to mitigate the impact of maintenance of tables (like bulk deletion of old data, rebuilding indices etc). Most of those tasks can be accomplished by having partitioned table and partitioned index. Having 10 foreign key indexes on a table can impact performance heavily than having one parent table and one foreign key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96991/discussion-between-vikas-pandya-and-durga-viswanath-gadiraju).